# Apache Ignite data rebalancing problem (Will not own partition (there are owners to rebalance from)

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I updated Apache Ignite to version 2.15.0
Everything is fine when I launch the first node, it works, the client connects to it. 
But when I launch the second node, an error occurs at the balancing stage, as far as I understand
Messages like this start to appear in the logs:

```
[2023-07-25T12:50:39,248][DEBUG][exchange-worker-#50][GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl] Will not own partition (there are owners to rebalance from) [grp=CustomCacheItem, p=3, owners = [TcpDiscoveryNode [id=2cb9ce8d-2025-456d-82a6-c761ef7a98b7, consistentId=1NodeHostname, addrs=ArrayList [20.20.28.215, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [1NodeHostname/20.20.28.215:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1690278575122, loc=false, ver=2.15.0#20230425-sha1:f98f7f35, isClient=false]]]
```

Then there are these errors appear:

```
[2023-07-25T12:50:55,935][ERROR][tcp-disco-msg-worker-[2cb9ce8d 20.20.28.215:47500]-#2-#44][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=partition-exchanger, threadName=exchange-worker-#50, blockedFor=16s]
```

And second node is shutting down

My questions:

1. Does the message "Will not own partition (there are owners to rebalance from)" relate to the cause of the second node crash?
2. If yes, what should I do? What is this message about?
3. How to understand what is causing the message "Blocked system-critical thread has been detected"

It seems that the problem occurs during rebalancing. But what exactly is the problem?

Comment: You should take a thread dump from the failed node. For some reason PME is stuck on the second node. It might be related to an ongoing transaction or something else.

Comment: PME is Power Management Event?

Comment: Partition Map Exchange, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/%28Partition+Map%29+Exchange+-+under+the+hood

Comment: Partition Map Exchange - Ok, got it.

Comment: Took a thread dump immediately after the first error message appears:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E2lMLUf8d8mkN0tRSP97GTrsZ3omddId/view?usp=sharing